# 3D region growing in PointCloud

Tags: 3d, point-clouds

My question is : Is there a way to to a region growing on a 3D pointcloud?
What I want to achieve is to find a region from a seed with all the points laying on the plane caracterized by the normal of my seed.

If I could, I would have used a sub-part of my PointCloud, and then look at all the points that lay on the right plane. But here, I have to do something like a region growing because I have to find a shape that is fixed on the wall, surrounded by a little area of crap. And because I don't know exactly the dimension of my shape, I could take point that belong to the wall.
So I have to start from a point that belong to my shape, and then grow a region around this seed until I find the crap border that caracterize the outlines of my shape.

I understand how to use a region growing on a grid, but I don't understand how to do it with a pointcloud (where points aren't aligned).

Do you know how to achieve that? Or do you know another way to do ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very fluent in english so I don't fully understand the middle paragrpah of your question, but, in order to learn how to do region growing on point clouds you could check this tutorial:

http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/region_growing_segmentation.php

Which also comes with some example code.

Comment: That is effectively what I had in mind, but I have to create a function that stop once it finds a point that is not part of the region, so it can't go "outside" my shape.